# Remove indent on ul tag inside a td

Tags: html, css

Basically, I am trying to align the bullets in the same line as the above td tag content inside a table.But the UL tag by default adds up an indent.

I tried adding `margin:0, padding:0,` it actually removes the bullets all together.I want to align the sentences in the same line with out removing the bullets.

Basically in the below jsfiddle example : heading2 column should be all aligned up right, meaning content and bullets should start from the same point

HTML :

```
<table class='table_css'>
    <th>heading1</th>
    <th>heading2</th>
    <tr><td>row1</td><td>content in row 1</td></tr>


    <tr>
        <td>some heading</td> 
       <td>
<ul> 
  <li>some text which is very long</li>
  <li>some text which is very long some text which is very long</li>
  <li>some text which is very long some text which is very long some text which is very long</li>
 </ul>
        </td>
           </tr>    
</table>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
    margin:0;

}

.table_css{
    border:1px solid;border-collapse: collapse;table-layout:fixed;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wgt7bsee/)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid; the only `<th>`, and `<td>`, elements must be wrapped in `<tr>` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want is `list-style-position: inside;`. Also, fix your html as there is a row missing around your `th`s.

https://jsfiddle.net/wgt7bsee/1/

Answer (score 2):

Just add a padding of 15px to the left to align the heading and bullets horizontally.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.table_css {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<table class='table_css'>
  <th>heading1</th>
  <th>heading2</th>
  <tr>
    <td>row1</td>
    <td>content</td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td>some heading</td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>some text which is very long</li>
        <li>some text which is very long some text which is very long</li>
        <li>some text which is very long some text which is very long some text which is very long</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```